# How can you detect a 500 Internal Server Error using Capybara?

Tags: cucumber, capybara, poltergeist

I want to test whether some URLs are broken or not.

Now I just assert some words I know are on these pages. I feel this isn't the best that i can do. Any help?

Comment: This question actually has quite a lot of possible answers. Are you testing a Rails app? Are you using RSpec or some other test framework? Would it be OK to use a unit test instead or are you testing a remote application?

Comment: i'm using Cucumber & Capybara & Poltergeist , testing a remote Rails application, but , anyway, thank you ,I figured it out, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out,
You Can detect *"500 Internal Server Error"* using [poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist)

> **Inspecting network traffic**
>   You can inspect the network traffic (i.e. what resources have been loaded) on the current page by calling page.driver.network_traffic. This returns an array of request objects. A request object has a response_parts method containing data about the response chunks.

so, this will work :

```
page.driver.network_traffic.each do |request|
  request.response_parts.uniq(&:url).each do |response|
    puts "Error : #{response.url}" if response.status == 500
  end
end
```